# JSON won't parse Java list object

Tags: json

I am working with JSON and i have data to send in JSON form.I have field `"stavka"` which should be list of JSON objects,`[{},{}...]`,and i have `niz=["{"redni_broj":"3","naziv_robe_usluge":"gwe","kolicina:2","umanjeno_za_rabat":"43","ukupan_porez2":"33"}", "{"redni_broj":"9","naziv_robe_usluge":"12a","kolicina:55","umanjeno_za_rabat":"12","ukupan_porez2":"2"}"]`,and so I did `"stavka":niz` within JSON.stringify function,because niz looked as list of JSON objects..But when I send it,it says

> "Can not construct instance of..no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from String value
>   ('{"redni_broj":"3","naziv_robe_usluge":"gwe","kolicina":"123","jedinica_mere":"12","jedinicna_cena":"54","vrednost":"12","procenat_rabata":"1","iznos_rabata":"2","umanjeno_za_rabat":"43","ukupan_porez2":"33"}')

Does someone know why this happens?Shouldn't this be working?I thought it is the same as explicitly doing `"stavka":[{"redni_broj":"3","naziv_robe_usluge":"gwe","kolicina:2","umanjeno_za_rabat":"43","ukupan_porez2":"33"}",{"redni_broj":"9","naziv_robe_usluge":"12a","kolicina:55","umanjeno_za_rabat":"12","ukupan_porez2":"2"}]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as your example niz is list String, not list of object. niz=["", ""] should be niz=[{}, {}].

Comment: What is wrong with my question?I searched previously internet,and I didn't find the answer,so I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

there are some syntax error in your code. First, you can't write the array like this

```
niz = ["{"redni_broj":"3","naziv_robe_usluge":"gwe","kolicina:2","umanjeno_za_rabat":"43","ukupan_porez2":"33"}", "{"redni_broj":"9","naziv_robe_usluge":"12a","kolicina:55","umanjeno_za_rabat":"12","ukupan_porez2":"2"}"],
```

maybe you means `niz` is an array like `niz = ['xx', 'xx']`, but you just the `"` not `'`, `"{"redni_broj":"3","naziv_robe_usluge":"gwe","kolicina:2","umanjeno_za_rabat":"43","ukupan_porez2":"33"}"` is not a string, it is wrong way to use like that.

`'{"redni_broj":"3","naziv_robe_usluge":"gwe","kolicina:2","umanjeno_za_rabat":"43","ukupan_porez2":"33"}'` is right way.

Or you can try to use it like this way
`"{\"redni_broj\":\"3\",\"naziv_robe_usluge\":\"gwe\",\"kolicina:2\",\"umanjeno_za_rabat\":\"43\",\"ukupan_porez2\":\"33\"}"`